# Strange issue with "Strange issue with X and Y" titles

Tags: discussion, title

This is something I'm completely on the fence about and would like some input from others. I occasionally come across a question with a title like "Strange issue with PHP and XML".

Is this considered a good title for a question? Whilst on one hand I suppose it gives a little insight into what the question is "Okay it uses PHP and XML, and something seem to be behaving in an undefined manner", I can't help but feel it's a bad title.

Should these be avoided/edited with a better title?

Comment: Titles should reflect the actual issue- So "Strange issue" with anything is a pretty crappy title. If you're writing a question, avoid a title like that. If you think you can edit to make the title reflect the actual issue, I'd say go for it!

Comment: For questions like those (if I'm knowledgeable of the subject), I try to edit the title so that it's more likely to be found when searching.

Comment: I doubt most people will be searching online for help with the phrase "strange issue". That'd be like trying to find a link by googling "click here".

Comment: @Trobbins - No, that was for the OP. I agree with you, though now I can see how that's unclear.

Comment: My codez haz not werkz, uz can plz fix? Only xprtz plz.

Comment: @TinyGiant ur code not usin jqueery. That ur prblem!

Comment: Tanks in advantage.

Comment: The same could be said for "tricky" and "difficult" problems.  The person solving the problem is a much better judge of how strange/tricky/difficult the problem truly is.

Comment: Unless I can see the question, I can't really judge whether it's practical to write an accurate description of the problem in the title.

Comment: The title here is a meta-title, folks; if it's good or useful, only a meta-editor should decide, or not! Going deeper to reflect the actual feeling of enthusiast programmers and end-users, a good title should be: *Paranormal issue with X and Y*.

Comment: "Strange" is like "help" or "no clue" or "frustrated"--it's about the poster's personal relationship to the problem, not about the problem itself. (The problem is likely not strange to somebody.) So it doesn't help others who might visit the page, so I think it makes sense to edit out. (At the same time, natural that people post like that--I wouldn't scold.)

Comment: Once you've edited the title to remove the tags (and possibly added the appropriate tags - but that's where those items belong) you're left with "strange issue" - and that doesn't help anyone know what the question is really about.

Comment: What I read: *problem [php] [xml]*... not really much information provided (plus the two tags should go as tags not in the title just to add a few chars)

Comment: The title is still better than: *Pulling my hair off for the last two hours on this issue*

Comment: What about issues related to the [Strange framework](http://strangeioc.github.io/strangeioc/)? :)

Comment: @vard again that should be a tag not in a title if it's a framework it should be tagged as that framework not titled with it.

Comment: @MartinBarker There is no problem to use a framework name in a title, if it makes sense as part of the sentence. That is a difference with using a framework name as a tag inside the title.

Comment: My experience is that most questions that start with "Strange issue..." actually aren't that much of a strange issue at all. Often the OP has overlooked something obvious.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Well...**no**.  Even though writing a title can be tough, these titles are utter crap and should be edited out.

First, look at it objectively from the standpoint of someone that wants to answer the question.  What is the "strange issue" that they're encountering?  Does it really relate to the technology(ies) that they've listed in the title?  From the answer's standpoint, they want to be able to concisely and definitively answer the question, as opposed to throwing darts on a board.

Now, look at it from the standpoint of someone that has a similar problem.  People describe problems in different ways, so the likelihood of them being able to relate to the "strange problem" is very, very slim.  However, if there's a common phrase in the title - say, "Failed to load ApplicationContext", then that's significantly easier to find, and gives a better description of what the actual problem is (as well as a moment of sympathy for the searcher, as they realize that they're not the *only* one having trouble with Spring wiring).

If you've got the chance to truly understand what's going on with the question, and you feel that it has a chance to be saved, then feel encouraged to edit the title with something more descriptive.  If there's missing context or information, put it on hold and <s>wait</s> hope for the OP to return to provide more context so a better title can be added.  It may also help to add driving questions as a comment, such as, "What are you trying to accomplish?"

Comment: I don't disagree, but there are times when there really is a "strange" situation that defies easy summarization in a sentence, or at least a summarization that's significantly more useful than the list of tools involved. Weird behaviors that involve particular confluences of configurations, parameters, or tool operations can be hard to describe succinctly. It's just such situations that lead to some questions, I'm sure, since general Internet searching can be hard as a consequence of the complexity and inscrutability of an issue.

Comment: That  said, I just went back and fixed one of my own question titles :)

Comment: @Pointy you can mention in the content that you think it's "strange", but it's very subjective, it shouldn't be in the title. If you, or the OP, can't fix it maybe an answerer can (and should). "Strange" will still be google-able if it's in the content but honestly that's a terrible search term - you'd have to be very lucky to get a hit it.

Comment: @AndyHayden Don't get me wrong, I totally agree with that. I'm just saying that people who resort to that aren't necessarily being lazy; the really vexing issues with odd platform/tool bugs can be very difficult to describe and very difficult to research for that reason. Even with good titles here, in fact, it may be a long shot that others with the same issue will choose the same way of describing the "strange" problem.

Comment: @Pointy which is why closing as duplicate keeps the old title searchable and just redirects. If you phrase it differently that's ok. "Strange" not so much, if I'm an answerer I'll make the title-edit but try to use similar language even if not technically accurate etc. :)